# Change data type of column in laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I have a column which i set enum earlier,
$table->enum('column_name', ['value1', 'value2']);

Now i want to change that into string without losing data.

I am using postgres database.

please help me,

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You Actually cant change type of enum column with simple migration

How i achieved it was using the `DB::statement` to alter the column type

```php
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY <column_name> VARCHAR(200)');
```

I'm not sure about the `postgres` You can modify query according to your need. Do make backup 1st **we aren't sure if it will make you lose your data**.

Answer (score 0):

In plain SQL the solution is more something like "ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER  COLUMN column_name SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR(20)".

For example:

```
postgres=# create table tenum(x serial, y enumval);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# select relfilenode from pg_class where relname='tenum';
 relfilenode 
-------------
       61038
(1 row)

postgres=# insert into tenum(y) values ('val1');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# insert into tenum(y) values ('val2');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select * from tenum;
 x |  y   
---+------
 1 | val1
 2 | val2
(2 rows)

postgres=# alter table tenum alter column y set data type varchar(20);
ALTER TABLE
postgres=# select relfilenode from pg_class where relname='tenum';
 relfilenode 
-------------
       61042
(1 row)

postgres=# select * from tenum;
 x |  y   
---+------
 1 | val1
 2 | val2
(2 rows)

postgres=#
```

Note that PostgreSQL will rewrite the table due to data type change.